# Laravel api authorization with api_token

Tags: php, laravel, api, routes, token

I am trying to create a Laravel API project. So I have this project with basic laravel's scaffolding set up. In my user migration I have added:

```
$table->string('api_token', 60)->unique();
```

then in my User.php model i have added:

```
 protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password','api_token'
];
```

Then in my api.php i have made a test route:

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api']], function(){

```
Route::get('/test', 'ApiController@test');

});
```

in my Apicontroller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ApiController extends Controller
{


public function test(Request $request){

return response()->json(['name' => 'test']);


}



}
```

so now i type this : with my api_token

```
localhost/project1/public/api/test?api_token='hsvdvhvsjhvasdvas8871238'
```

It's not giving me the json data, instead it's redirecting to the logged in home page

Comment: try localhost/project1/test?

Comment: thx SteD for the reply..i fixed it. its a silly mistake i made. didn't include the /api in the route. but now i have another problem please see my edited question.

Comment: @SteD sorry, its silly mistakes again. i fixed it :) sorry again my bad should have been a little more patient lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`localhost/project1/public/index.php/api/test?api_token='hsvdvhvsjhvasdvas8871238'` would help.

If you want pretty urls, read the documentation: [Pretty URLs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/installation#web-server-configuration)

Comment: It's not a safe practice to send the token via GET params.

Answer (score 1):

For laravel 5.2
Middleware/ApiAuthenticate

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class ApiAuthenticate
{

    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->guest()) {
            return response()->json(['status'=>'error','message'=>'token mismatch']);;
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Kernel.php add

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'autho'      => \App\Http\Middleware\ApiAuthenticate::class,
];
```

routes.php

```
    Route::group(['prefix'=>'api','middleware'=>'autho:api'], function(){
        Route::get('aaa','Api\AAAController@index');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You would not have to write your own API middleware and routes if you use Laravel 5.3 or higher version.

Moreover, you can use the in-built [Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport) package to manage the access token, using oAuth2.

```
$http = new GuzzleHttp\Client;

$response = $http->post($apiUrl.'oauth/token', [
    'form_params' => [
        'grant_type' => 'password',
        'client_id' => '2', //this can be generated when you setup Passport package or using artisan commands
        'client_secret' => 'xxxxxxxxx', //this can be generated when you setup Passport package or using artisan commands
        'username' => 'a@a.com',
        'password' => 'test123',
        'scope' => '',
    ],
]);

$responseData = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);

$token = $responseData['access_token']; //Now I have the token so I can call any protected routes 

$response = $http->request('GET', $apiUrl.'api/v1/user', [
    'headers' => [
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$token,
    ],
]);

$responseData = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
echo "Name of the user is: ".$responseData['name'];
```

Comment: Thx tanay jha for the reply. I tried following the passport documentation. but it's kinda hard , cuz it's talking about vue.js and gulp front end stuffs. which is pretty confusing.

Comment: @MohamedManas you don't really need to use Vue.js, that is only required if you want your frontend to be Vue.js based. See my edited answer.